# refactoring long url in an API call

Tags: php, refactoring

I have the following code:

```
if ($utm_source) {
    $url = "http://xxx.yyy.zzz/u/register.php?CID=815112955&f=472&p=2&a=r&SID=&el=&llid=&counted=&c=&optin=y&interest[]=[Interessen]&inp_3=".$email.'&inp_1005='.$utm_source;
} else {
    $url = "http://xxx.yyy.zzz/u/register.php?CID=815112955&f=472&p=2&a=r&SID=&el=&llid=&counted=&c=&optin=y&interest[]=[Interessen]&inp_3=".$email;
}
```

Is there a way to refactor this so that the URL may not need to be this long? Something like a URL array or something to keep the base url and the uri separate.

Comment: When you make an API call, your URL has to be complete anyway. Why make it shorter?

Answer (score 0):

In Index File You Just Define Your Base URL like this

```
define('BASE_URL','http://xxx.yyy.zzz/u/register.php?CID=815112955&f=472&p=2&a=r&SID=&el=&llid=&counted=&c=&optin=y&interest[]=[Interessen]&inp_3=');
```

After that You Will make like this

```
 $url = BASE_URL.'?Something';
```

Hope it will solve your Problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$url = "http://xxx.yyy.zzz/u/register.php?CID=815112955&f=472&p=2&a=r&SID=&el=&llid=&counted=&c=&optin=y&interest[]=[Interessen]&inp_3=".$email.'&inp_1005='.$utm_source;
  $result = shortenurl($url);

  function shortenurl($url)
    {
     if ( strlen($url) > 45) {
      return substr($url, 0, 30)."[...]".substr($url, -15);
     } else {
      return $url;
     }
  }
```

**Result :**

> http://xxx.yyy.zzz/u/register.[...]np_3="$email"&inp_1005="$utm_sourc"

Answer (score 0):

I am working on angular, i define a environment variable:

```
  export const environment = {
         my_api: 'http://xxx.yyy.zzz/u/register.php? 
         CID=815112955&f=472&p=2&a=r&SID=&el=&llid=&counted=&c=&optin=y&interest[]= 
         [Interessen]&inp_3=' };
```

You can call it on your file:
      private static api_url = environment.my_api;